# disp(fprintf()) prints the fprintf and the number of characters. Why?

Tags: matlab, printf, disp

By coincidence I discovered, that `disp(fprintf())` prints the string of fprintf plus the number of characters that it has. I know, that the `disp()` is reduntant, but just out of pure curiosity I want to know, why it prints the number of characters, since this might be actually helpful one day.
For example

```
disp(fprintf('Hi %i all of you',2))
```

results in

> Hi 2 all of you    15

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for the specific behaviour mentioned in the question is the call to FILEprintf [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) with a storage variable:

> `nbytes = fprintf(___)` returns the number of bytes that `fprintf` writes, using any of the input arguments in the preceding syntaxes.

So what happens is that `disp(fprintf(...))` first prints the text as per `fprintf` without a storage variable, but `disp` sees only the storage variable of `fprintf`, which is the number of bytes of your string, hence the output.

As an addition, if you want to display strings, you need STRINGprintf: [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html):

```
disp(sprintf('Hi %i all of you',2))
Hi 2 all of you
```

What the docs show me is that `sprintf` is exclusively used for string formatting, which you can use for adding text to a graph, setting up sequential file names etc, whilst `fprintf` writes to a text file.

> `str = sprintf(formatSpec,A1,...,An)` formats the data in arrays `A1`,...,`An` according to `formatSpec` in column order, and returns the results to string `str`.
>
> `fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,A1,...,An)` applies the `formatSpec` to all elements of arrays `A1`,...`An` in column order, and writes the data to a text file. `fprintf` uses the encoding scheme specified in the call to `fopen`.
>
> `fprintf(formatSpec,A1,...,An)` formats data and displays the results on the screen.

For displaying text on screen therefore `disp(sprintf())` or `fprintf` are equal, but if you want to store the results in a string you have to use `sprintf` and if you want to write it to a text file you have to use `fprintf`.

Comment: is there a difference in behaviour between this and just using `fprintf` without the `disp`?

Comment: The nice thing about `sprintf` is that you can construct strings as you want it to; e.g. I use it to plot "The area of the polygon is %d sqm" on my graphs. `sprintf` can also be used to generate sequential filenames, i.e. `sprintf('SequentialFile_%i.mat',LoopVariable)`. I'll check the exact differences, as I rarely use `fprintf`

Answer (score 7):

In the doc on [`fprintf`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html?refresh=true), you see that the output from `fprintf` is the number of bytes printed. So here, the `fprintf` is printing `Hi 2 all of you` and the `disp` is printing the 15 returned by `fprintf`.

Comment: I see, thank you. But how did you find this doc? When i use `doc fprintf`, i find this one: http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fprintf.html

Comment: @Max In addition to what HBHB said: if you want to avoid that behaviour use `sprintf` instead of `fprintf`