# Difference between disp and fprintf

Tags: matlab, disp

In Matlab, it seems to me that `disp` and `fprintf` commands both are very similar in that they both show to display what you tell it to. What is the difference between these 2 commands?

Comment: refer [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/9701-sprintf-or-disp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `disp`, it displays the **value of variable**.

For example

```
>> a = 1; disp(a)
     1
```

Another example.

```
>> disp('example')
example
```

Note, `'example'` can be seen as a variable

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html

---

For `fprintf`, if you are talking about displaying to the screen, the format is

> fprintf(formatSpec,A1,...,An) formats data and displays the results on
>   the screen.

**The difference to `disp` is that it doesn't display the value of variable unless you specify format string**

For example, if you tend to display the value of a variable, you get an error

```
>> a = 1; fprintf(a)
Error using fprintf
No format string.
```

You need to specify the format string. For example, the format string is `'The value of a is %d\n'`

```
a = 1; fprintf('The value of a is %d\n',a)
The value of a is 1
```

If you are talking about writing data to text file, the format is

> fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,A1,...,An) applies the formatSpec to all
>   elements of arrays A1,...An in column order, and writes the data to a
>   text file. fprintf uses the encoding scheme specified in the call to
>   fopen.

For example

```
fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'The number is %d\n',1);
fclose(fileID);
```

View the contents of the file with the `type` command.

```
>> type exp.txt

The number is 1
```

The `fprintf` can also return the number of bytes that fprintf writes. [Refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33519743/8569905)

Reference: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html